# How to make 2 columns from a csv of the same length

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to make 2 columns the same length when they have a different length.
So I just want to cut the longer column to match the shorter one.
The first line of the if statement works fine but I get an error when I want to change the data

```
if data[str(data.columns[in1])].count() > data[str(data.columns[in2])].count():
    data[str(data.columns[in1])] = data[str(data.columns[in1])][0:data[str(data.columns[in2])].count()]
elif data[str(data.columns[in2])].count() > data[str(data.columns[in1])].count():
    data[str(data.columns[in2])] = data[str(data.columns[in2])][0:data[str(data.columns[in1])].count()]
```

It looks a bit wierd because I use the variable "in1" and "in2" as an input to select different columns without changing the code. They are just a numbers between 0-19 because I have 20 columns in my csv.

I don't know why it's not working. As far as I know you can change a column like this:

```
data["Column"] = data["Column"][0:1000]
```

This should also work:

```
data["Column"] = data["Column"][0:data["Column2"].count()]
```

I just can't figure it out :(

Comment: when you load csv into df you get Nan values for shorter columns?

Comment: I use this data to make a linear regression and with nan values the regression line is not working correctly. That's why I just want to cut the longer column

Comment: after load data into df use: `df = df.dropna()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are slicing the column and that will not change the whole df structure, it will just be NAN values for the other outside the sliced rows.
see below code

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_json(b'{"num1": [1, 2, 3], "num2": [4, 5, 6]}')
df["num1"] = df["num1"][0:1]
# df[0:1] run this to compare
```